# delete polictDef in ApiMan via GUI

Tags: apiman

I have added `Policy Definition` wrongly instead adding it as custom `Plugin`.

```
  "id": "test-policy",
  "policyImpl": "plugin:${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}:${project.packaging}/io.apiman.plugins.test.TestPolicy",
  "name": "Test Policy Plugin",
  "description": "Test policy plugin",
  "icon": "lock",
  "templates": [],
  "formType": "JsonSchema",
  "form": "schemas/test-policyDef.schema",
  "deleted": false
}
```

Now if I try to add the plugin, it complains that the *plugin with name already exist*. There is only option to update policy and if i try to set `"deleted": true`. It does not update at all as I can see the configuration remains unchanged.

How can I delete this `policy definition` and install it as `plugin`. I think I can change to new `"id"` and add it as `plugin`. Is it possible ? But is there no way to delete the `policy` directly ?

EDIT : I can add it as plugin with new `"id"` as it the `primary key` in ES registry. But still cannot find a way to delete it. Where are the `policydefs` stored in the system? Can we delete using ES query?

Comment: Suggest you come onto our mailing list for this (apiman-user - https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/admindb/apiman-user). I'm not entirely sure from you explanation what you've done.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the mailing list.